# Satisfy all the given conditions, and get 4 separate output lists, for the given conditions

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, set

Create four lists satisfying conditions below

1. Students who play all the three sports
2. Students who play both cricket and football but don’t play hockey
3. Students who play exactly two of the sports
4. Students who don’t play any of the three sports

   Input 1:

   ```
    c = [2, 5, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

    a = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 16]

    b = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of operation you can convert your lists to sets and perform set operations.  For instance :

```py
# 1
set(a).intersection(set(b).intersection(set(c)))

# 2
set(a).intersection(set(b)).difference(set(c))
```